# What are the differences between: LauncherPro "Keep in memory" and "Lock home in memory."

Tags: cyanogenmod, home-screen, launcherpro

- LauncherPro has an option for "Keep in memory".
- CyanogenMod settings has an option for "Lock home in memory".

How do these work? Do they conflict with each other? What problems might they cause? The CM version seems to work better, but causes other apps to shut down.

Answer (score 2):

I keep them both enabled, but I have tried them each individually and the CM option works much better.  The fact that it "causes other apps to shut down" is the whole point.  Android keeps the memory filled at all times and ends tasks on demand when more memory is needed.  It is supposed to be pretty smart and know, based on your usage, which apps to give priority to but if you are multi-tasking and the phone needs more memory it may kill LauncherPro causing it to to reload from scratch when you hit the home button.  The option to keep it in memory gives it a higher priority so when Android tries to free up some memory it kills something else.

Comment: Yes, but it seems to kill the app I'm currently using.  I'm guessing the slow startup of LauncherPro could be made faster if it stored more information before being shut down?

Answer (score 2):

The CM option is going to have more sway with the OS than the LauncherPro option (since it is the CM option is from the OS itself vs an app telling the OS to not kill itself).

I've also had even better success with screen redraws [using this method](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/8597-virtually-eliminate-homescreen-redraws/page__p__75864__hl__redraw__fromsearch__1#entry75864).  I think it's what the CM toggle is supposed to do, but this actually does it.

> 1) MAKE A NANDROID BACKUP
>
> In your terminal application on your
>   phone (if you have to ask what this
>   is, Google it, download it from the
>   market)

```
su (enter) 
echo ro.HOME_APP_ADJ=1 >> /data/local.prop (enter)
reboot (enter)
```

> If you want to undo what this command
>   does, simply remove that toggle from:
>   /data/local.prop, or if you did not
>   have this file (like I did not) prior
>   to the mod...remove it entirely