# Homescreen is blank on 2.2 Droid

Tags: motorola-droid, home-screen, launcher, ram

I have a Motorola Droid on Verizon, and a lot of times when I unlock it, my homescreen will be blank; no icons, no widgets. Nothing in my app tray, either. I have to wait for about a minute for everything to load before I can launch anything (unless the app I just used was one of the 6 most recent, in which case I can long-press Home with no problem).

I think the problem is a lack of memory; my phone is probably auto-killing the launcher constantly. When I use an option on a third-party launcher to avoid closing the launcher, I don't have this problem anymore, but I'll often be kicked out of the app in the foreground!

Now for my system details... I'm currently running Cyanogenmod 6.1, but it was doing this before I rooted (in fact, I mainly rooted because I thought it would fix the problem). I'm using ADW.Launcher as well, but again, it was doing this with the stock launcher. I'm also not using any task killer apps.

Has anybody else had this problem? I haven't talked to any other Android users who have mentioned this.

Comment: Do you mean that your homescreen is empty (no icons) or blank (no icons or wallpaper)? If you still have your wallpaper, I'm having this problem with LauncherPro on my Moto Droid (also VZW) running CM 6.1.2.  Its odd though because I've been running this configuration for over a month and this just started happening.  Further confusing me I haven't really installed anything new so I don't see any significant change that would be causing this.  That being said it could have been an app update but I haven't really spent any time diagnosing it.

Comment: FWIW, I'm plagued by the same issue. It's a large part of the reason I went to Zeam instead of the default launcher. It's better, but not by much. And I'm running stock Android.

Comment: I mean it has no icons and wallpaper. It may be important to mention that I currently have ADW.Launcher set to never close, but this often causes other important apps to be killed.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this from the [CM forums](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/8597-virtually-eliminate-homescreen-redraws/page__p__75864__hl__redraw__fromsearch__1#entry75864):**

If you use ADW or LauncherPro and if after using any memory intensive application you hed back to your Homescreen... you know the drill.....lag, lag, redraw, redraw, then finally you are able to function again.

1. MAKE A NANDROID BACKUP
2. In your terminal application on your phone (if you have to ask what this is, Google it, download it from the market) enter...

> ```
> su (enter) 
> echo ro.HOME_APP_ADJ=1 >> /data/local.prop (enter)
> reboot (enter)
> ```

If you want to undo what this command does, simply remove that toggle from: /data/local.prop, or if you did not have this file (like I did not) prior to the mod...remove it entirely

This is also from [Bryan Denny's Answer to this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3151/launcherpro-keep-in-memory-vs-lock-home-in-memory/3158#3158).

You'll probably still have a problem with foreground apps closing when you keep your launcher in memory but I think that's just an issue with trying to use too many memory intensive apps with a phone with 256 MB of RAM.

**You can also try to take the memory priority management into your own hands with [AutoKiller Memory Optimizer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/autokiller-memory-optimizer/com.rs.autokiller).**  It allows you to set your own custom minfree priorities for Android to follow.

Comment: I don't have the problem with it closing anymore, but now foreground apps are being killed (presumably to free resources). I'll try AutoKiller to make sure that important apps at least aren't dying (i.e. my alarm app).

I guess the only real solution is to get a new phone with more memory? :/

Comment: I suspect its time for a new phone.  I just got a used Fascinate (Galaxy S). I haven't rooted it yet but its much snappier even running 2.1 than my Droid.  I haven't made the full switch yet so I'm still lagging most of the time on the Droid.